# Font appears bigger in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, font-size

I don't understand why the fonts are bigger in IE8 and IE9. I am using Helvetica font. All other browsers are okay. I got problem only in IE8 and IE9. The line-height is also bigger. I cannot post the Link to my site here for some reason. But it's really simple use of css. Here is how my HTML header looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="se">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Digi...</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/layout/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

</head>
```

Comment: So where is your CSS? We can't help without your CSS ;)
Your `<head>` is useless in this case. The `viewport` meta-tag is for other devices like smartphones to make sure you can't scale the viewport and always get the correct initial scale.

Comment: You are correct Imrul.H. Text does appear different on different browsers. It's a fact of life. http://css-tricks.com/font-rendering-differences-firefox-vs-ie-vs-safari/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is truly vital, and you do not mind using Conditional Comments to send IE-targeted CSS to the browser, you can create a Conditional Comment stylesheet for IE like:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ie9.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Otherwise, a good first step is to always use a CSS Reset to normalize between browsers. Commonly used resets is `YUI`.

see this: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

Answer (score 0):

Yes IE change the way he read the css or the styling from one version to another. In general its only the distance calculation that change. So all the padding/margin. line-heigh etc. The same way that when you look at a website in chrome,firefox,saferie,ie the website isn't exactly the same.

```
If the problems is really important for you (normally I ajust the css so that even with the         difference the website) you can use CSS Conditionnal comment like this :
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="ie ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ie ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

If you use css:

```
.ie8 body {
//IE 8 CSS
}
.ie9 body {
 //IE 9 CSS
 }


Or use the tag on you're meta tag
<!--[if IE 8]><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.8, minimum-scale=0.8, maximum-scale=0.8"><![endif]--> 
(or change the scale to whatever you want) do the same for IE 9.
```

Edit:

Sorry @Tasos and @user3830694 I was slow to write the post and saw that you provided similar answer by the time I was finished :P

Answer (score 0):

Try modernizr. It will try to normalize the CSS styling between different browsers.

http://modernizr.com/